# XSLT to use HTML numbers not HTML names when encoding symbols?

Tags: html, xslt, encoding

At the moment we use symbols such as `£` which will come out as
    `&pound;` -

But is there a way in XSLT to force symbols like this to use the number variant, for example `&#163;`?

We need to be able to convert all symbols that have HTML names such as 
    `&pound;` `&copy;` 
etc.

Comment: Which XSLT version and which XSLT processor do you use? I think http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#HTML_CHARDATA suggests for XSLT 2.0 and the `html` output method that entity references are preferred over character references so you will need to check whether you XSLT processor has an option or setting to get HTML output with numeric character references instead of entity references. XSLT 2.0 has has character maps as a brute force method to map characters to a certain representation, thus if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor that is an option.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: It seems to me that the question is asking for the reverse -- represent a character with its character entity references only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:output encoding="ascii"/>
```

This forces the serializer to output the corresponding character entities reference for any character whose numeric value is greater than 127.